# Python 3.3: Split string and create all combinations

Tags: python, regex, list, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.3. I have this string:

```
"Att education is secondary,primary,unknown"
```

now I need split the last three words (there may be more or only one) and create all possible combinations and save it to list. Like here:

```
"Att education is secondary"
"Att education is primary"
"Att education is unknown"
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = "Att education is secondary,primary,unknown"
first, _, last = data.rpartition(" ")
for item in last.split(","):
    print("{} {}".format(first, item))
```

**Output**

```
Att education is secondary
Att education is primary
Att education is unknown
```

If you want the strings in a list, then use the same in list comprehension, like this

```
["{} {}".format(first, item) for item in last.split(",")]
```

**Note:** This may not work if there are spaces in the middle of the comma separated values or in the values themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = "Att education is secondary,primary,unknown"
last = a.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]
chopped = a[:-len(last)]

for x in last.split(','):
    print('{}{}'.format(chopped, x))
```

If you can guarantee that you words are delimited with a single space this will also work (more elegant):

```
chopped, last = "Att education is secondary,primary,unknown".rsplit(maxsplit=1)
for x in last.split(','):
    print('{} {}'.format(chopped, x))
```

Will work fine as long as the last words' separator doesn't include whitespace.

Output:

```
Att education is secondary
Att education is primary
Att education is unknown
```

Comment: Little inefficient, you might want to do `a.rsplit(" ", 1)`

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain how is `split` better than `rsplit` with `maxsplit` set to 1?

Answer (score 2):

```
s="Att education is secondary,primary,unknown".split()

w=s[1]
l=s[-1].split(',')

for adj in l:
    print(' '.join([s[0],w,s[2],adj]))
```